# Error while using rSymPy

Tags: r, rjava

I recently installed rSymPy to perform some symbolic calculations in R. This step also installed some dependencies (“rJava”, “rjson” and “rJython”). After the installation was complete, I loaded the library and ran a very simple command which gave me an error:

```
> library("rSymPy")
Loading required package: rJython
Loading required package: rJava
Loading required package: rjson
> x <- Var("x")
Error in .jcheck() : No running JVM detected. Maybe .jinit() would help.
```

Here is my sessionInfo(), just in case you need it:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
[3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8  
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C  
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
other attached packages:
[1] rSymPy_0.2-1.1 rJython_0.0-4  rjson_0.2.15   rJava_0.9-8 
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2 tcltk_3.2.2
```

I have tried to install different versions of required packages, but I always get this error. I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Aashish

Comment: See https://github.com/ggrothendieck/rsympy/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gabor Grothendieck (developer of rSymPy) for pointing out that sometimes one needs to manually initialize JVM. One can simply use "sympyStart()" at the beginning of the code, and that fixes the error.